# Can I reference an external sgml declaration from within a sgml document?

Tags: include, sgml

I'm more used to xml documents and tools, but I need to deal with sgml.  I have an sgml document that I'm using `nsgmls` to parse, and I need to include a particular sgml declaration with it.  It works fine if I specify the declaration file on the command line:

```
$ nsgmls mydoc.decl mydoc.sgml
```

But I'd like to include the reference to the declaration within the sgml file (and not the entire declaration).  Including it like a xml doctype i.e., `<!DOCTYPE MyDoc SYSTEM "mydoc.decl">` fails with

```
mydoc.decl:1:2:E: unknown declaration type "SGML"
```

and the declaration isn't parsed (leading to lots of other errors).  Trying to do the same thing as a SGML declaration: `<!SGML MyDoc SYSTEM "mydoc.decl">` isn't any better, that gives me a fatal error:

```
mydoc.decl:1:0:E: character "<" invalid: only minimum literal and parameter separators allowed
mydoc.decl:1:0:E: cannot continue because of previous errors
```

Is there any way to just reference the external file, or will I always need to specify it on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference the SGML declaration from the DOCTYPE declaration. The DOCTYPE declaration should only point to the DTD.

What you can do though create a file named `catalog` (no extension) with an `SGMLDECL` entry in it. If you put this file in the same location as your SGML document, nsgmls will use it.

You can also point to the catalog file using `-c` on the command line, but that would defeat the purpose for you since you're trying not to reference anything else from the command line.

Here's an example `catalog` file pointing to a different SGML declaration file:

```
SGMLDECL somedir/mydoc.decl
```

If you have that catalog file in the same directory as "mydoc.sgml", you can leave the sgml declaration out of the command line:

```
nsgmls mydoc.sgml
```